# Selecting the max of a count column with a group by in spark sql

Tags: sql, group-by, apache-spark-sql

I have the following data:

```
yr char cnt
1   a   27
1   g   20
3   b   50
3   z   70
```

I like to get the year, only max count of cnt field. i.e,

```
yr char count
1   a   27
3   z   70
```

I tried to use a SQL like below:

```
SELECT yr, char, max(count(cnt)) as count
FROM view
GROUP BY yr,char
```

But it resulted in an error saying the max cannot be used with count in SparkSQL. How can I get the result I want as shown above?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
sql("select a.yr, a.char, a.cnt from view a join (select yr, max(cnt) as cnt  from view group by yr) b on a.yr = b.yr and b.cnt = a.cnt").show()
```

Answer (score 0):

This would often be done using `row_number()`:

```
select yr, char, cnt
from (select yr, char, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by yr order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from view
      group by yr, char
     ) yc
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  In the event of ties, this returns an arbitrary one of them.  If you want all of them, use `rank()` or `dense_rank()`.

Comment: Unfortunately that query doesn't work in SparkSQL due to the unavailability of row_number. Is there any other way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: @Neo . . . What version are you using?  They've been supported for quite a while (https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html)